# Printing single comma (or other char) in Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a seemingly very small problem, but I can't find a solution for it:

Within a Razor view i have something like this:

```
<p>
@if (someCondition){
   foreach (Sometype s in Model.ListOfSomeTypes){
      @s.Name @//There is a space in front here.
   }
}
</p>
```

But I want to have to have all the names comma seperated, so i essentially want to do something like this:

```
<p>
@if (someCondition){
   foreach (Sometype s in Model.ListOfSomeTypes){
      @s.Name, 
   }
}
</p>
```

However, Razor freaks out. How can I achieve this kind of result?

---

I have tried some variations like this:

```
@{','} @s.Name @//No good
@"," @s.Name @//No good
@{","} @s.Name @//No good
@StringVariableContainingComma @s.Name @//This works, but seems to be very unnessecary to me.
```

Ps. I know that the above suggested solution for comma seperated elemens don't work propperly. Removed conditions for easier reading of question.

Comment: All of the approaches below seem valid. Take a look at - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use regular brackets to specify an [explicit code nugget](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/16/asp-net-mvc-3-implicit-and-explicit-code-nuggets-with-razor.aspx).

```
@(s.Name), @(...)
```

Comment: Nice, I hadn't seen this before, so much nicer than `text` tags.

Answer (score 5):

The `<text>` tag should do it for you.

```
<p>
@if (someCondition){
   foreach (Sometype s in Model.ListOfSomeTypes){
      @s.Name<text>, </text>
   }
}
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it - though you'll have trailing comma

```
@foreach (Sometype s in Model.ListOfSomeTypes){
    @(s.Name+",")
}
```

or

```
@if (someCondition){
   @String.Join(",", Model.ListOfSomeTypes.Select(s => s.name));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>
@if (someCondition){
   foreach (Sometype s in Model.ListOfSomeTypes){
      @s.Name<span>, </span>@s.City
   }
}
</p>
```

you can use a span tag